# Ask an Expert popup window

Tags: popup

Today while looking for some answers I got a 'popup window' with the heading of 'Ask an Expert'  It wasn't really a popup, seemed more like javascript. Clicking on the 'window' You get a chat box with an 'expert'. The 'expert' is always funny but not very knowledgeable. Asking what company this person represents I get, "that depends". Very interesting conversation I must say. I've checked all running processes and don't see anything that I don't recognize. Virus scan has come up clean. Is this something related to stackoverflow? I haven't seen it on other sites that I've browsed. While it was funny, I need to know if I need to backup my important data and apply a good disk image. Thanks for any help.

Comment: [April fools!!!!!!!!!!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: AHA, that makes scence. Anyone else getting this April fools joke?

Comment: I saw it earlier today, yes.

Comment: Right on. That's the best April fools joke I've seen yet. I was really ready to go into disaster recovery mode. I even started making a list of what programs I would need to re-install after I imaged my computer

Comment: I thought this looked a lot like a rework of Elize, but with some topical semantic linkage.  I wasn't sure for a while if it was a bot or a person acting like one. :-)  I hope we'll see the full story tomorrow.  Thanks for the reminder on what day it is, this had me going for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it too, it gives authomatic responses, it's a robot for April's fools joke, don't worry it's not a virus :)

Comment: it's not a real person? the answers were pretty good. Great joke!!

Comment: haha yes, but sometimes it repeats the same things over again, or it doesn't make a lot of sense. It's pretty funny though, I found myself talking to the "expert" for a pretty long time instead of working...

Comment: lol, thats funny. I was trying everything I learned to find the virus. I really didn't want to use an image that was 6 months old

Comment: Cute, got this as well, but pretty obvious it was a bot, and it admitted it too.

Comment: grr, wasting my time!

Comment: Now I feel bad that I got annoyed and typed "are you sure you're an expert?" to one of my questions.